# validating triangular relationships in postgres with/without RLS

Tags: postgresql

I am looking at [this documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-rowsecurity.html) and I'm finding it hard to understand. Esp this part which seems counter-intuitive:

> Referential integrity checks, such as unique or primary key constraints and foreign key references, **always bypass row security** to ensure that data integrity is maintained. Care must be taken when developing schemas and row level policies to avoid “covert channel” leaks of information through such referential integrity checks.

Say I'm creating a new row in a table named *things*, with data like

```json
{ owner_id: 123, thing: "ball", box_id: 5 }
```

- `owner_id` references `members.id` in members table *[id, username]*
- `box_id` references `boxes.id` in boxes table *[id, owner_id, capacity]*
- Intention is members *can* have option to put some of their things into boxes they own.

**Q1: If I DO NOT have RLS enabled anywhere:**
How do I make postgres ensure that when a thing is created, that box is *actually* owned by the person pointed to by owner_id. Is it possible without RLS? If so, how?

**Q2: If I DO have RLS enabled:**
How do I make postgres enforce that the box referenced actually belongs to the owner referenced by `owner_id`? The examples show `FOR [SELECT|UPDATE] USING (...)` etc. Does that cover "REFERENCES" action entirely?

Hope the question makes sense. I don't know the proper name for this kind of check.

Comment: Your data model is bad, and `things` shouldn't have a foreign key to `members`. The ownership is sufficiently clear from the `boxes`. If you disagree, perhaps you have a good reason. Please edit the question and state it.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Good question. The thing is that a member can be an owner of things, that they never put into any boxes. Free radical things. That was the reason.  Is that still a bad reason? Should things just have an optional _box_id_. OMG... they should, shouldn't they? 0.o **update** wait, no. Because then how would we know who the un-boxed things belong to?

Comment: If `box_id` is nullable, that is a good enough reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to guarantee that the owner of a thing and its containing box are the same, add a redundant unique constraint to `boxes` that contains both the `id` and the `owner_id` of the box. Then define the foreign key on `things` using both columns.

Comment: Can you help a newbie out? So boxes already has `id uuid primary key default gen_random_uuid()`  and `owner_id uuid not null` . I guess "add a redundant unique constraint to boxes" means **replace** existing primary key with `primary key(id, owner_id)`? How do I then reference that from _things_? I don't think I've ever referenced a composite key. Also would I still need to do all this after figuring out how RLS works and trying to implement it? Thanks!

Comment: No, you don't remove the existing primary key. You add another unique constraint, which will be the target of the foreign key. The documentation of `CREATE TABLE` and `ALTER TABLE` show the syntax to define a foreign key with two columns.

Comment: learned a lot. Thanks!